# How to load custom fonts so I can use them in DirectX?

Tags: c++, memory, fonts, directx, loading

Hello I'm curently working on a game in DirectX and I know how to crate a font and draw text with that font and this is how I do it.

Here I create my Font.

```
D3DXCreateFont(D3DDevice, // The device
               20,                        // Font size
               0,                         // Default width
               FW_NORMAL,                 // Font weight
               1,                         // MipMap
               false,                     // Italic
               DEFAULT_CHARSET,           // Charset
               OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // Output precision
               DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // Quality
               DT_LEFT | DT_TOP,          // Default pitch & family
               "Arial",                   // Font name
               &ArialFont);               // Font object
```

Here is my `RECT` for when I display my font.

```
RECT FontRect;
FontRect.left          = 50;         // xPos
FontRect.top           = 50;         // yPos
FontRect.right         = 800;        // maxX Cutoff
FontRect.bottom        = 600;        // maxY Cutoff
```

Here I display my font.

```
ArialFont->DrawTextA(NULL,                                  // Sprite
                     "Test Text",                           // Text
                     strlen("Test Text"),                   // Text length
                     &FontRect,                             // The font RECT
                     DT_LEFT | DT_TOP,                      // Format
                     D3DXCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));        // Color
```

But you can see that when I created my font the second last parameter was just the font name and since I just have to write the name it means that that font has to be installed into my computer right?
Now my question is how can I load a font from a file into memory or whatever for just when I run this program so I can have a 'Custom Font'?

Answer (score 2):

You can temporaly install a custom font (e.g. a .ttf-file) at the start of your program. Therefore you can use the WinApi-Method `AddFontResourceEx()` ([msdn-doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to load a font to the system. If you flag it with `FR_PRIVATE`, it's only usable of your process and will be automatically removed, when the process terminates. With `RemoveFontResourceEx()` ([msdn-doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you can manually remove it. The usage of the installed font in DirectX is simply via it's name.